# Как получить регулярным выражением строку между символами?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Допустим есть строка `[Hello world]` нужно получить содержимое `[]` без самих `[]`.

В JS нет поддержки групп, а как сделать без них я не знаю.

Comment: Как это нет поддержки групп, если есть?

Answer (score 2):

Не обязательно же регулярки использовать:

```js
let str='blabla [Hello world] blabla';
console.log(str.slice(str.indexOf('[')+1,str.indexOf(']')));
```

Если ж прям регуляркой, то похитрим:

```js
let str='blabla [Hello world] blabla';
console.log(str.replace(/^.*\[/g,'').replace(/\].*/g,''));
```

Comment: В моем случае обязательно

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас дополню ответ..

Comment: Взятие подстроки, а не замена.

Comment: Я Вам сейчас Америку открою - исходная строка осталась не тронутой.

Comment: `console.log(str.replace(/^.*\[/g,'').replace(/\].*/g,''),str)` => `"Hello world"  "blabla [Hello world] blabla"`

Answer (score 2):

Здрасьте, с чего вы взяли, что группы не поддерживаются?

```js
const str = '[hello world]';

const result = str.match(/\[(.*)\]/);
console.log(result);
```

Первый элемент - это вся найденная строка, далее идут группы по мере их появления ( от самой внешней до самой внутренней и слева на право )

```js
const regEx = /(.{3}(.{2}))\s(.)/;
const str = 'hello world';

const result = str.match(regEx);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Классный ответ :) Положу себе в копилочку - у меня с регулярками не очень :(